# Are GPS coordinates determined via data transfer?

Tags: gps

I'm running on Android 4.2 and I have an app that sends data (via 3G) to my server including my current GPS coordinates. Sometimes, however, my data gets sent but the GPS coordinates are left blank.

Is it possible for my Android device to be able to send / receive data, but not be able to triangulate my location?

I'm trying to figure out if this is a flaw in my app or if I am having GPS signal strength issues.

Comment: @AndrewT. I Think I'm still a little bit confused about something. Does this mean I can get my location using 3G? Also does this mean the hardware behind GPS is different inside my device than the hardware that is used for data?

Comment: Possible. You may want to refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631811/how-to-know-the-positioning-mode-is-wifi-or-2g-3g-cell-tower-in-android

Comment: You must distinguish between "GPS location" and "network location" here (and probably also cell-based location, depending on implementation). If e.g. GPS cannot get a lock, and you have the others turned off, you might be "left without position", so to speak. Check the question Andrew marked already (and its answers), it's explained pretty well there.